# Getting NumberFormatException for TextView.getText()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm a beginner who's been desperately trying to understand how to achieve the following thing: I have 3 TextView displaying 3 numeric values (always integers) on screen as text, such as: 50, 100, 200. Then, after some event, I want these 3 strings to be put as values in my PieEntries 
in the ArrayList. I can't just get the text from the TextView and put it as a value for the entry, so I tried to use **Integer.parseInt** to read the Strings as an Ints (since they are actually made of all numbers), or also Integer.valueOf but I only get ***java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "First"*** error after the crash. This is the part I'm talking about:

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> myData(){
        ArrayList<PieEntry> myArray = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();

        arrayValue.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(TextView1.getText().toString()), "First"));
        arrayValue.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(TextView2.getText().toString()), "Second"));
        arrayValue.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(TextView3.getText().toString()), "Third"));
        return graphValues;
    }
```

I won't paste the whole code here since the graph actually works fine if I manually put values instead of trying to parse the integers from the TextViews.
Also: when I first start to type "new PieEntry", the hint clearly says that it's gonna require a "float value" (then a drawable or a string and so on). Is this where the troubles begin? Should I convert Strings into Integers (or into Floats?) in some way before? I guess there's just like some basic Java rule I'm ignoring, so I'd like to understand what is happening here and how to face this. Many thanks!

Comment: May I suggest that you add a print statement to check the value of at least on of the TextView's. Something like System.out.println("myData: TextView1 = *" + TextView1.getText().toString() + "*"); That way you could check if the string is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Ok, here is the thing: by default, I gave my three TextView "android:text="First", "Second" and "Third" to begin with. Then, through the user input in an EditText (one for each TextView) and pressing a button, the typed values (integers required!) replace the "First", "Second" and "Third" labels. When I try to print the string as you suggested, I get back the initial text I gave to the TextView (like "First"), not the user-written numbers, even if I try to print that when the user has successfully changed the TextView with his typed number. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I used SharedPreferences to store the new typed data as Integers and retrieve them whenever I need them:

Setting up my Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences myPreferences;
savedData = getSharedPreferences("myStoredData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Saving an Integer for later:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = savedData.edit();
myEditor.putInt("Label", int);
myEditor.apply();
myEditor.commit();
```

Retrieving and using the Integer:

```
savedData.getInt("Label", Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you Explained, you are not getting the TextView text, it is because maybe you have written it somewhere you should not, i.e. provide a Button, when the user types and is done he will hit the button say submit and do this above code on button click.

Comment: Thank you but, this being understood, I haven't figured out how to solve it yet